# How to pip in SageMaker Studio Lab

Tags: pip, amazon-sagemaker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l40ce.png)
I want to pip matminer in the jupyter lab but failed. If someone knows why and how to fix the problem

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/studio-lab-user/.conda/envs/default/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.22.1.dist-info/METADATA'

Answer (score 1):

I just ran it with no problems

```
%pip install matminer --user
```

I did use a % instead of a ! per the best practices.

Comment: I haven't seen `%`  before commands used in Jupyter notebooks on platforms other that aws sagemaker studio. Is this something AWS only?